# Pivot Table Error in Pivot Cache "Type Mismatch"

Tags: excel, vba

When trying to run this code, I continue to get

> run time error 13 "Type Mismatch"

when setting the pivot Cache and I am not sure what is causing the issue.  I have tried both `PivotCaches.Add` and `PivotCaches.Create` and both give the same error.  Any Ideas?

```
Sub NEWPIVOTERROR()
    
    'Declare Variables
    Dim PSheet As Worksheet
    Dim DSheet As Worksheet
    Dim PCache As PivotCache
    Dim PTable As PivotTable
    Dim PRange As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastCol As Long
    
' Assembly Engineer

    Sheets("Assembly Engineer").Activate

    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Assembly Engineer Charts"
    Set PSheet = Worksheets("Assembly Engineer Charts")
    Set DSheet = Worksheets("Assembly Engineer")
    
    'Define Data Range
    LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)
    
    'Define Pivot Cache
    Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add _
    (SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange). _
    CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(2, 2), _
    TableName:="AssemblyEngineerPivotTable")
    
    '?Insert Blank Pivot Table
    Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable _
    (TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="AssemblyEngineerPivotTable")
    
    'Insert Row Fields
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("AssemblyEngineerPivotTable").PivotFields("Task Owner2")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
    End With
    
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("AssemblyEngineerPivotTable").PivotFields("Type")
    .Orientation = xlColumnField
    .Position = 1
    End With

    'Insert Data Field
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("AssemblyEngineerPivotTable").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables("AssemblyEngineerPivotTable").PivotFields("Type")

End Sub

Sub NEWPIVOTERROR()
    
    'Declare Variables
    Dim PSheet As Worksheet
    Dim DSheet As Worksheet
    Dim PCache As PivotCache
    Dim PTable As PivotTable
    Dim PRange As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastCol As Long
    
' Assembly Engineer

    Sheets("Assembly Engineer").Activate 'Edit

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Worksheets("Assembly Engineer Charts").Delete 'Edit
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Assembly Engineer Charts" 'Edit
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Set PSheet = Worksheets("Assembly Engineer Charts") 'Edit
    Set DSheet = Worksheets("Assembly Engineer") 'Edit
    
    'Define Data Range
    LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)
    
    'Define Pivot Cache
    Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
    (SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange). _
    CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(2, 2), _
    TableName:="AssemblyEngineerPivotTable") 'Edit
    
    '?Insert Blank Pivot Table
    Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable _
    (TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="AssemblyEngineerPivotTable") 'Edit
    
    'Insert Row Fields
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("AssemblyEngineerPivotTable").PivotFields("Task Owner2") 'Edit
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
    End With
    
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("AssemblyEngineerPivotTable").PivotFields("Type") 'Edit
    .Orientation = xlColumnField
    .Position = 1
    End With

    'Insert Data Field
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("AssemblyEngineerPivotTable").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables("AssemblyEngineerPivotTable").PivotFields("Type") 'EditX2

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a Range object doesn't work well with big datasets. Use the address instead:

```
Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="'" & DSheet.Name & "'!" & PRange.Address(Referencestyle:=xlr1c1)). _
CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(2, 2), _
TableName:="AssemblyEngineerPivotTable")
```